# Choukai discussing a business trip

Tags: readings, listening

I am practicing my choukai using this [link](https://jlptsensei.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/JLPT-N3-Practice-Test-listening-script.pdf). In the passage 6 of mondai 1

My understanding after reading the whole passage is that the lady is supposed to plan a trip. However, I did not understand the following sentence.

> **M:** で、そこで何をするかだな。 食事しただけで終わるのは、ちょっとな。

I translated in my mind as follows:

> So, Next would be what to do there (after the arrival). After having a meal, we have a little time left.

I did not understand the relevance of this sentence here. Can somebody help?

Comment: Not native so I wait for someone else but I read it as, 


"Hmm... I wonder what we should do there"


"Ending the trip after just having food is little... "

She is implying that just dinner is a little bit too little before ending the trip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding of the first sentence is fine, but you've parsed the second sentence wrong. This ちょっと is a way of avoiding saying something negative directly. Something along the lines of "a little...um..." or "...you know". Everything before は is the subject (nominalized verb).

> [食事しただけで終わる**の**]は、ちょっとな。
> [Just having dinner (together) and being done with it] is...y'know.